# How average two rows after eachother in R but only for specific columns

Tags: r

I want to be able to average the odba column and the minute column ONLY depending on the rows on top of each other. For instance, row 1+2 would be averaged, then row 2+3, then 3+4, etc. If someone could give me some code that could do this that would be awesome! The name of the row would just be the average then of the minutes column.

Furthermore, technically I want to be able to just have an odba measurement every 15 minutes...so for the 15 minute mark, the odba measurement would be the average of the 10 minute mark and the 10 minute mark. I didn't know if that would be too difficult because as long as the above issue is solved, I can filter by the rows I want.

```
> dput(head(turtlesacc_clean.1, n= 100))
structure(list(Turtle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("R3L1", 
"R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", "R8L4"
), class = "factor"), Day = structure(c(16579, 16579, 16579, 
16579, 16579, 16579, 16580, 16580, 16580, 16580, 16580, 16580, 
16580, 16581, 16581, 16581, 16581, 16581, 16581, 16582, 16582, 
16582, 16582, 16582, 16582, 16583, 16583, 16583, 16583, 16583, 
16583, 16584, 16584, 16584, 16584, 16584, 16584, 16584, 16585, 
16585, 16585, 16585, 16585, 16585, 16586, 16586, 16586, 16586, 
16586, 16586, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16588, 
16588, 16588, 16588, 16588, 16588, 16589, 16589, 16589, 16589, 
16589, 16589, 16590, 16590, 16590, 16590, 16590, 16590, 16633, 
16633, 16633, 16633, 16633, 16633, 16634, 16634, 16634, 16634, 
16634, 16634, 16634, 16635, 16635, 16635, 16635, 16635, 16635, 
16636, 16636, 16636, 16636, 16636, 16636, 16637), class = "Date"), 
    Minute = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 20L, 
    30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 
    30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 
    20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 
    20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 
    20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 
    20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 1L, 
    10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L, 
    10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 0L), meanodba = c(0.0131682810769231, 
    0.0238000364166667, 0.018957617, 0.0048715435, 0.02218334225, 
    0.00941444583333333, 0.0714711534166667, 0.245915521, 0.213012161916667, 
    0.10459259375, 0.09160222825, 0.0657544175, 0.0775775118333333, 
    0.0520835475384615, 0.0228336625833333, 0.0267944869166667, 
    0.0112685870833333, 0.0327017893333333, 0.0305357829166667, 
    0.0447806983076923, 0.0381606105, 0.00379524925, 0.0297376309166667, 
    0.0132207086666667, 0.0104253506666667, 0.0175778505384615, 
    0.0275432004166667, 0.0318361995, 0.0726917810833333, 0.0308402895833333, 
    0.03358500025, 0.0800982955, 0.158703777, 0.0690775005, 0.0421694353333333, 
    0.0461304373333333, 0.07674433775, 0.0838157903333333, 0.0290208969230769, 
    0.0296452505, 0.03839616725, 0.0133708225833333, 0.0256290334166667, 
    0.0365729786666667, 0.0205466634615385, 0.0187344295, 0.0388302530833333, 
    0.0245862598333333, 0.02076905875, 0.00878493566666667, 0.00242616215384615, 
    0.00218942041666667, 0.0026103445, 0.00228666025, 0.00232174583333333, 
    0.00229049233333333, 0.00252677615384615, 0.00241023633333333, 
    0.0024513895, 0.0022465105, 0.0025435495, 0.002524973, 0.00349326392307692, 
    0.00225489175, 0.00306012908333333, 0.00324679391666667, 
    0.00800508075, 0.00440377016666667, 0.00414924623076923, 
    0.00321832183333333, 0.00332649283333333, 0.00259779133333333, 
    0.0120080429166667, 0.00298526025, 0.0927059689230769, 0.143522624416667, 
    0.126670176833333, 0.17085910675, 0.11083877025, 0.0995038140833333, 
    0.2159300075, 0.002322521, 0.1754120805, 0.08432479125, 0.129686415083333, 
    0.125385988333333, 0.0917711481666667, 0.0774774747692308, 
    0.0839409246666667, 0.0531362301666667, 0.088240564, 0.0529548980833333, 
    0.0974778426666667, 0.0376906349230769, 0.0315978985833333, 
    0.01603981125, 0.0509367594166667, 0.00611242633333333, 0.0624609059166667, 
    0.0333324461666667)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    Turtle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("R3L1", "R3L11", 
    "R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", "R8L4"), class = "factor"), 
    Day = structure(c(16579, 16580, 16581, 16582, 16583, 16584, 
    16585, 16586, 16587, 16588, 16589, 16590, 16633, 16634, 16635, 
    16636, 16637), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 
        7:13, 14:19, 20:25, 26:31, 32:38, 39:44, 45:50, 51:56, 
        57:62, 63:68, 69:74, 75:80, 81:87, 88:93, 94:99, 100L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floor division (`%/%`) to break `Minute` into 15-minute chunks. Using dplyr to group and summarize:

```
library(dplyr)

turtlesacc_clean.1 %>%
  mutate(
    Min15 = (Minute %/% 15) * 15,
    Min15 = paste0(Min15, "-", Min15 + 14, " min")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Turtle, Day, Min15) %>%
  summarize(
    across(Minute:meanodba, mean),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 65 × 5
   Turtle Day        Min15     Minute meanodba
   <fct>  <date>     <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 R3L1   2015-05-24 0-14 min    5     0.0185 
 2 R3L1   2015-05-24 15-29 min  20     0.0190 
 3 R3L1   2015-05-24 30-44 min  35     0.0135 
 4 R3L1   2015-05-24 45-59 min  50     0.00941
 5 R3L1   2015-05-25 0-14 min    3.67  0.177  
 6 R3L1   2015-05-25 15-29 min  20     0.105  
 7 R3L1   2015-05-25 30-44 min  35     0.0787 
 8 R3L1   2015-05-25 45-59 min  50     0.0776 
 9 R3L1   2015-05-26 0-14 min    5     0.0375 
10 R3L1   2015-05-26 15-29 min  20     0.0268 
# … with 55 more rows
```